# How to inject script code in head?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have profile user page `index.blade.php` where I should to shoe Google map.
This template looks like:

```
@extends('users.index')

@section('content')
   <script>Google scripts</script>
@endsection
```

So, when page is rendered I get outpus as:

```
  <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <script>Google scripts</script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

So, when I do HTML validation onlne, I get error, that you can not use `scripts` in body. It should be in HEAD.

Is there an way to do this in Laravel?
I dont want to load Google script on each pages.

Comment: So what is the problem? Create a new section `css` and inject them to.

Comment: Sorry, I changed title of question

Comment: :) Anyway u can create any section what you like to. And insert it where do u want.: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: Consider using slots/components: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots

Comment: So mu code will be: `  @slot('google-scripts')
        <script></script>
    @endslot` ?

Comment: I would like to use old good sections. As you wish

Answer (score 0):

in index page make script in its head to check page URL and if matched requested url then load scripts in page like below

```
<script>
    const RequestedUrl = window.document.URL;
    function injectScript ( myScriptURL ) {
       let script = document.createElement("script")
       script.type = "text/javascript";
       script.src = myScriptURL;
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    if(RequestedUrl === 'http://your.URL') { // or RequestedUrl.includes('/cats') for ex.
       injectScript(//jquery script URL//);
       injectScript(//google script URL//);
    }
</script>
```

if it depended on jquery or any make sure to load it same way before google scripts

[learn more](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/)